# Validate multiple input fields in same form using vue 3 composition api

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs3

In my application, i have created custom validation and validators to validate different form field. The submit button will be disabled till all the inputs are not empty.

I have created validator like this adding rules.

// **validator.js**

```
export default function validators() {
      const isEmpty = (fieldName, fieldValue) => (!fieldValue ? `This ${fieldName} can not be empty` : '');
      const minLength = (fieldName, fieldValue, min) => (fieldValue.length < min ? `The ${fieldName} must be atleast ${min} characters long` : '');
      return {
        isEmpty,
        minLength,
      };
    }
```

Using this validator into validation logic for input and text area , email etc like below.
// **formValidation**

```
import { reactive } from 'vue';
import Validators from './validators';

const errors = reactive({});
const {
  minLength, isEmpty
} = Validators();
export default function formValidation() {
  const validateInputField = (fieldName, fieldValue) => {
    errors[fieldName] = !fieldValue
      ? isEmpty(fieldName, fieldValue) : minLength(fieldName, fieldValue, 2);
  };
  return {
    errors,
    validateInputField,
  };
}
```

Now, i have created custom button validation state like below. It is computed property.

**Button State**

```
import { computed } from 'vue';

export default function submitButtonState(field, errors) {
  const isButtonDisabled = computed(() => {
    let disabled = true;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
    for (const prop in field) {
      if (Object.hasOwn(field, prop)) {
        if (!field[prop] || errors[prop]) {
          disabled = true;
          break;
        }
        disabled = false;
      }
    }
    return disabled;
  });
  return {
    isButtonDisabled,
  };
}
```

Now, in my component i am storing all input variables into pinia store. After input , storing those variable is working properly but button state is disabled all the time. It is not updating at all.

**Here is the component code:**

```
<template>
 <div> 
  <span>Forms Description</span>
  <p>
  <my-textarea
        :message-type="errors.address ? 'negative' : ''"
        :validation-message ="errors.address"
        max-length="100"
      >
        <textarea
          v-model="formResponses.txtArea1"
          @blur="validate1stInput"
          @keypress="validate1stInput"
          slot="textarea"
          maxlength="100"
        ></textarea>
        <label slot="label" for="textarea"
          >Address</label
        >
   </my-textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
  <my-textarea
        :message-type="errors.comments? 'negative' : ''"
        :validation-message ="errors.comments"
        max-length="100"
      >
        <textarea
          v-model="formResponses.txtArea2"
          @blur="validate1stInput2"
          @keypress="validate1stInput2"
          slot="textarea"
          maxlength="100"
        ></textarea>
        <label slot="label" for="textarea"
          >Comments</label
        >
   </my-textarea>
  </p>
  <p><button class="myButton" @click.prevent="submit" :disabled="isButtonDisabled"</p>
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import UserStore from '@/store/userStore';  // pinia store variables are using to store input data
import FormValidation from '@/utilities/useFormValidation';
import SubmitButtonState from '@/utilities/SubmitButtonState';
import { ref, reactive, watch } from 'vue';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const { form1 } = storeToRefs(UserStore());
const formResponses = reactive({ ...form1.value });

const { validateInputField, errors } = FormValidation();

const { isButtonDisabled } = SubmitButtonState(formResponses, errors); // It is giving value true always after inputting correct value in field


const validate1stInput = () => {
  validateInputField('address', formResponses.txtArea1);
};
const validate1stInput2 = () => {
  validateInputField('comments', formResponses.txtArea2);
};

watch(() => errors, { immediate: true });

</script>
```

Button state is not updating i am not sure it might be not getting updated error state. How to fix this for multiple inputs?

**I have made a workable codesandbox but in my case in application 'formResponse' variables return empty so button state is always disabled(true).**

Codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-diffie-ymgtur?file=/src/utilities/FormValidation.js

Comment: Could you make a minimum reproducible example on https://play.vuejs.org/ or https://codesandbox.io/. Otherwise it's boring to make that job for you

Comment: Ok i can give the link

Comment: yes, give the link pls

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch the state change via a computed property (here with typescript):

```
const isButtonDisabled: ComputedRef<boolean> = computed((): boolean => SubmitButtonState(formResponses, errors) );
```

Comment: Same. It is still giving true value.

Comment: @learningMonk I'll interfere later

Comment: How to get the updated state value immediately because it is not updating? Where I missed to update the variable as reactive